# Minimum operation to make an array good

Tags: c++, arrays

You are given an array A containing N integers. You are also given an integer K. An array is good if `A[i]<=A[i + k]`, `i = 1, 2, 3,.., n - k`
In one operation, you can choose any element and convert it to an arbitrary integer.

**Task**

Determine the minimum number of operations to make the array good.
Note: Assume 1-based indexing.

**What I tried**

```cpp
int lis(std::vector<int>& a){

    if(a.size() == 0) return 0;

    vector<int> b;

    b.push_back(a[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++){

        if(b.back() <= a[i]) b.push_back(a[i]);

        else{

            int idx = lower_bound(b.begin(), b.end(), a[i]) - b.begin();

            b[idx] = a[I];

        }

    }

    return b.size();

}


int minOperations(int n, vector<int> a, int k){

    int cost = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){

        vector<int> b;

        for(int j = i; j < n; j+=k) {

            b.push_back(a[j]);

        }

        cost += b.size() - lis(b);

    }

    return cost;
}
```

*It is partially correct*

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: This question was asked in Amazon Test on HE platform. Am I right??

Comment: for (int i=0;i<N-K;i++)  {If(A[i]>A[K+i]&& K+i<N) count++;  // Not required -->but including it for reference  if(A[i]<=A[i+K]) continue;} @SHARMIN AHMED

Answer (score 1):

If k=1, the condition is met when the array is sorted.
If k=2, the condition is met if the array slice with indices [0, 2, 4, 6 ...] is sorted and the array slice with indices [1, 3, 5, 7, ...] is sorted.

Basically, you split the array into k sub-arrays and then have to ensure that these slices are sorted. Correct?

In that case all you have to do is create a custom iterator that increments by the given value k, then call sort on all sub-arrays.

The minimum number of operations is now the number of operations in your sort algorithm. If you only need an estimate, I'd go with O(k * (n/k * log(n/k))) = O(n log(n/k)).

If you actually need to count operations, you need to override the swap and compare operations inside std::sort, which is doable but I'm not writing the code before you verify that this is what you need.

Comment: for (int i=0;i<N-K;i++)  {If(A[i]>A[K+i]&& K+i<N) count++;  // Not required -->but including it for reference  if(A[i]<=A[i+K]) continue;}

Comment: @chandru Could you elaborate? You're not counting enough operations to sort the slice. Also, the second part of the if statement (```K+i<N```) is superfluous. Your loop is stopping before the condition is reached. In any case, the check would be too late. Given the order of operations, you would have accessed A beyond its limit already

Comment: I'm trying to count the values which is [i]>[i+k] and K+i<N is to check whether i+k is within the array limit , not exceed the limit N . Nothing much @Homer512

Comment: @chandru The count would not be sufficient to make the array "good", however, because simply swapping ```A[i]``` and ```A[K+i]``` does not guarantee that ```A[i] >= A[i-K]``` (the previous one) will hold. It's like one round of bubble sort. The ```K+i<N``` check is unnecessary because your for loop is already only going to ```i<N-K```

Comment: Since it required only operations count so I thought to count but not swapping. and also I tried adding K to A[0 to N] but that didn't work. The problem is check the minimum operation required to make an array as good so we need only the number of operations count.